# opencv image processing method recommendation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pyautogui, matchtemplate

so im working on a program thats comparing a screen shot with a template image. ive finished the image recognition code ( most of it atleast ( from what i know )) but it keeps getting false positives. right now im using CV_TM_CCOEFF but i still dont fully understand how each of these work ( i suck at math and this is the one a friend recommended ) if i happen to already be the correct one any advise on this would be much appreciated.
code :

```
import pyautogui as cpt
import cv2
import imutils
import time
time.sleep(3)
def show(x):
    cv2.imshow(x,x)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
path2=r"C:\Users\assaw\OneDrive\Desktop\projectpy\0.png"
template=cv2.imread(path2)
w=template.shape[0]
h=template.shape[1]
method=5
a=cpt.screenshot(region=(70,40, 100,400))
a = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(a),cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imwrite("picture.png",a)
img= cv2.imread("picture.png")
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,method)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
top_left=max_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
cv2.rectangle(res,top_left, bottom_right, 100, 1)
cv2.imwrite("local.png",res)
im= cv2.imread("local.png")
show(a)
show(im)
```

on a side note if anyone can explain this line of code on how it works it would be appreciated

```
top_left=max_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
cv2.rectangle(res,top_left, bottom_right, 100, 1)
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain what the code is supposed to do and what is the error you are facing?

Comment: Example images can be helpful for the question. You can think template matching algorithm like you slide the template over the picture and choose the point where it fits the most to the picture. If you want, you can choose a threshold and eliminate bad matches for cases where the template is not present in the picture. The method you choose affects that threshold.